# Making similar app as already existing on App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

Are there some restrictions for making an exact copy (with our own branding) of an app/game that is already there on App Store? i.e. copying the idea

Comment: big difference between using the idea and "making an exact copy with our own branding"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 2.11 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) is interesting.

> Apps that duplicate apps already in
>   the App Store may be rejected,
>   particularly if there are many of
>   them, such as fart, burp, flashlight,
>   and Kama Sutra apps.

As usual, you can't be sure if it is allowed.
But if it's not another fart app and you put effort in your project (ie extend the idea you "copy" with some cool functions or if you use a different way to do the same thing) the chance of a rejection is very very small.

Getting inspiration is always ok. Everybody does it.

Answer (score 3):

Other than being sleazy and immoral?

Comment: @beer_monk: Excuse me? If the idea is not patented, why should it be immoral? Should there be only one shop in the world making fried chicken? Doesn't Apple, Microsoft, Samsung, Google, all copy each other when an idea is a hit?

Comment: It's immoral if you copy an app, and it becomes more successful than the one you copied for no good reason (eg just due to publicity, rather than it doesn't crash) Apple, MS, Samsung and Google are in competition, there's a difference between competition and copying. How would you like it if someone copying your app/software.

Comment: @Doc: If the idea is patented it's illegal, but this has nothing to do whether it's moral or not. If you just copy someone's app which he has potentially put lots of effort thinking in it, it's still immoral regardless of the legal aspect.

Comment: @frenetisch applaudierend ; @Jonathan: i agree in general, but there are also other "copy" apps which don't really "copy" any original idea. Consider all that classic games which existed before iPhone (chess, dama, poker...) and which everybody has the right to use... Or some touristic app-info which describes some artistic city as Venice, Rome... Don't tell me that the first who put his app in appStore get the exclusive copyright on Venice...

Comment: @meronix: I think copying a good "idea" and create another maybe similar app around it is perfectly ok (I guess this counts as "inspiration"). But "exact copy" sounds very different.

Comment: @frenetisch applaudierend: yeah, right, that's the part that i do agree

Answer (score 1):

There are apps that provide a variation on a theme - for example, there are many "to-do list" apps. Each provide their own take on the core requirement, but each developer implements it in a slightly different way.

Your question specifically states that you wish to make an "exact copy". You may wish to review/research how you could add value or provide an alternative implementation to differentiate your app from the existing offering.

Specifically addressing your question, [Apple's app store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) state:

*Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them, such as fart, burp, flashlight, and Kama Sutra apps.*

Answer (score 1):

You will need to consult with an intellectual property lawyer or attorney to determine if your copy violates anyone elses copyrights on materials or patents on implementation technologies.  Apple requires that you have the legal rights to use any copyrighted artwork or code (etc.) in any app you submit.  And any app idea not protected by patent or copyright may be fair game for copying legally, but Apple may still not want it in their store.

Answer (score 0):

Copying existing applications are perfectly normal and I encourage it. Under ONE condition, you improve upon the original idea. Lets take computers for example. The first computer was a tremendous leap forward. However, Most all PC's built today are called "clones", the reason...Because they were copies, all "stolen ideas" HOWEVER they were greatly improved upon. Social Networking, great idea, but it was the "stolen" concept that brought us from Myspace to Facebook, it was innovation and "besting" the already existing. Not every idea can unique but they can be better.